# call c# api async in forech loop

Tags: c#

I want to call c# web api in foreach loop without wait for response/Result. below example ...is it right way ?

```
int i = 0;

foreach(var item in items)
{
    i++;
    Console.WriteLine("call " + i.ToSring());

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(HubConnectionUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        //GET Method  
        await  client.PostAsJsonAsync<dynamic>("job/UpdateScanResult/", new { result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), TotalSize, interval, culture });



    } 
}
```

Comment: Example that ..?

Comment: `... without wait for response/Result` <= If you do not want to wait for the response how will you ever be able to check the response in the `if/else` block?

Comment: Dont new up a new `HttpClient` in a loop like this.  Use a single shared static instance.  You also need to `await` the response

Comment: can i call some thing like  Task.WhenAll

Comment: @RajeshKumar What do you mean by "can I call something like Task.WhenAll"? Have you tried it? What was the result? How did it not perform as expected?

Comment: @ mason i didn't try it.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Then why are you here asking questions on Stack Overflow if you haven't tried it? Go try it!

Comment: @mason if you can see below some one answered.

Comment: @RajeshKumar So they answered, why are you asking if you *can* do it? Go try it instead of asking us!

Answer (score 3):

To execute many tasks in parallel, the most simple and naive way to do it is to use [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
var tasks = items.Select(item => client.PostAsJsonAsync<dynamic>(...));

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Why do you suggest that solution when you call it `naive`? Wouldn't it be better if you suggested something that you do NOT believe is `naive`?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be better, this answer is to solve the solution the easiest way possible.  A non-naive solution would require additional information that isn't known from the question, such as rate limiting, concurrency, etc.  Instead I said this was a naive solution as an indicator that this isn't necessarily the best solution for all problems.

Comment: Thx, for the explanation.